# Fix bug setup data and delete data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord, discord.js

//setup

```
const data = verify.findOne({ guildId: interaction.guild.id });
      if (data == data)
        return interaction.reply({
          content: `You had create a verify panel yet!`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      if (!data) {
        verify.create({
          guildId: interaction.guild.id,
          roleId: role.id,
        });
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "Verification channel was succesfully set!",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
```

//delete

```
const data = verify.findOneAndDelete({ guildId: interaction.guild.id });
      if (!data)
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "This server didnt setup yet",
          ephemeral: true,
        });

      interaction.reply({
        content: `Succes delete data for **${interaction.guild.name}**`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });
```

Pls help me fix that! idk where is the error

when i use the delete data cmd, it doesnt delete the data from that guild

when i use the setup cmd when the guild already setup, it just create data and setup

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose methods like `findOneAndDelete()` or `findOne()` returns a promise. So you need to use **async/await** with them or **.then()/.catch()**
Eg-

```
const data = await verify.findOne({ guildId: interaction.guild.id });
```

Make sure your **exec**/**run** or whatever function the code is in, is defined as an async function to use await syntax.